# Reverse engineer Listen to this device on Windows - Reverse Engineer Windows When There's No API

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, autohotkey, reverse-engineering

I'm using autohotkey to write a script to toggle "Listen to this device" of my microphone:

[image: listen to this device]

There are two steps to accomplish this, first I needed to find out what Registry key is being modified, I was able to accomplish this using RegShot.

The key exists in:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture\{My-Microphone's-UUID}\Properties
```

The key is called `{24dbb0fc-9311-4b3d-9cf0-18ff155639d4},1` (Not just my laptop but for all computers).

And the value when toggling the "Listen to this device" changes like this: (The 0's change to f's)

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0000xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxffffxxxx
```

Step two is where my problem lies, when I check the GUI, I see that the "Listen to this device" tickbox has been ticked but I can't actually hear anything from my microphone, when I untick it then hit apply and re-tick it and click apply, I hear my mic. This means that I need some sort of DllCall or PostMessage here, but this is where I fall very short:

I don't know how to make windows understand that this setting has changed, I need to find out what messaged was sent or what dll was called when I click "apply".

So I googled [List of Windows Messages](https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages) and I literally posted every single one of the hexes that exist on the page like this:

```
PostMessage, 0x0000,,,,A
...
PostMessage, 0xcccd,,,,A
```

And it didn't work of course, it was a shot in the dark.

Using Autohotkey's WindowSpy on the Sound GUI and [from this article](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/126383-listen-microphone-through-playback-device-windows.html) I found out that `shell32.dll` might be involved in this, so using nirsoft's DLL Export Viewer I copied all functions that exist in `shell32` and I called all of them using Autohotkey like this:

```
DllCall("shell32\Control_RunDLL")
...
```

But this also didn't work.

At first I thought, this is a programming question where it can be answered with Autohotkey and it's tools, so I asked this question on SO, but I've asked to move it to RE as comments below gave me more insight.

Please teach me how I can reverse engineer this properly.

Comment: I hope I understand what you want, you are looking for at way to monitor if registery is changed in windows, is that correct? if yet check this https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSMonitorRegistryChange-d297cdf0/sourcecode?fileId=22029&pathId=1222468310

Comment: You should probably be using the [MMDevice API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/mmdevice-api) to make this change instead of writing directly to the registry.

Comment: As an aside, you can never figure out DLL calls by trial and error, because not only do you need the name of the exported function, you need the correct data type and value of each parameter.  The number of combinations grows exponentially.

Comment: This page on MSDN also looks relevant to routing incoming audio to the output: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/device-topologies

Comment: related discussion on MSDN forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/f243f5e2-c2ac-4cec-8f57-0825cab48af5/access-to-the-quotlisten-to-this-devicequot-setting?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks very much, from the links you've sent me, I've found `IMMNotificationClient::OnPropertyValueChanged The OnPropertyValueChanged method indicates that the value of a property belonging to an audio endpoint device has changed.` This is exactly what I need. So it says it's a `method`, I'm not sure if it can be used with AHK. I need to search :)

Comment: I think you could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) in the future to help you catch File System, Registry and other events.

Comment: Oh.. and in general.. window messages are just that.. window messages.  They aren't used to notify the system of a hardware change.

Comment: I've looked into all the comments, I thank everyone. And about the discussion on MSDN forums, here's a summary: someone reverse-engineers this and finds out a way to toggle "listen to this device" but the post gets removed by the Moderator.. this is sad, I screenshot it and highlighted it: https://i.imgur.com/HzkfBOQ.jpg I can't find any archive for it. And about `IMMNotificationClient`, it definitely doesn't work with Autohotkey.

Comment: @NetMage I did as you said, and I've found out in the process of toggling the option, `AudioEndpointBuilder.dll` and `Audiosrv.dll` were read. There wasn't anything else new.

Comment: And also found `AudioEng.dll` now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/31865/45094) on RE, I was able to come up with a proper code sample to both set whether listening is enabled/disabled, as well as which device it should be listened on - including the "Default playback device" setting.

It's in python using pycaw and comtypes, but it could just as easily be done with other languages that have coreaudio libraries I think.

```py
from typing import Optional
from comtypes import GUID
from comtypes.automation import VT_BOOL, VT_LPWSTR, VT_EMPTY
from comtypes.persist import STGM_READWRITE
from pycaw.api.mmdeviceapi import PROPERTYKEY

from pycaw.api.mmdeviceapi.depend import PROPVARIANT
from pycaw.utils import AudioUtilities

#Hardcoded values
LISTEN_SETTING_GUID = "{24DBB0FC-9311-4B3D-9CF0-18FF155639D4}"
CHECKBOX_PID = 1
LISTENING_DEVICE_PID = 0

#Values you can change:
microphone_name = 'Microphone (USB-MIC)'
listening_device_name = 'Speakers (5- GSA 70 Main Audio)'   #Set to 'None' to use the default playback device
enable_listening = False

def main():
    store = get_device_store(microphone_name)
    if store is None:
        print("failed to open property store")
        exit(1)

    set_listening_checkbox(store, enable_listening)
    set_listening_device(store, listening_device_name)

#Write to the checkbox property
def set_listening_checkbox(property_store, value:bool):
    checkbox_pk = PROPERTYKEY()
    checkbox_pk.fmtid = GUID(LISTEN_SETTING_GUID)
    checkbox_pk.pid = CHECKBOX_PID

    new_value = PROPVARIANT(VT_BOOL)
    new_value.union.boolVal = value
    property_store.SetValue(checkbox_pk, new_value)

#Write to the device property
def set_listening_device(property_store, output_device_name:Optional[str]):
    if output_device_name is not None:
        listening_device_guid = get_GUID_from_name(output_device_name)
    else:
        listening_device_guid = None

    device_pk = PROPERTYKEY()
    device_pk.fmtid = GUID(LISTEN_SETTING_GUID)
    device_pk.pid = LISTENING_DEVICE_PID

    if listening_device_guid is not None:
        new_value = PROPVARIANT(VT_LPWSTR)
        new_value.union.pwszVal = listening_device_guid
    else:
        new_value = PROPVARIANT(VT_EMPTY)

    property_store.SetValue(device_pk, new_value)

#Gets the device store from the device name
def get_device_store(device_name:str):
    device_guid = get_GUID_from_name(device_name)
    enumerator = AudioUtilities.GetDeviceEnumerator()
    dev = enumerator.GetDevice(device_guid)

    store = dev.OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READWRITE)
    return store

#This is just a helper method to turn a device name into a GUID.
def get_GUID_from_name(device_name:str) -> str:
    input_devices = get_list_of_active_coreaudio_devices("input")
    for device in input_devices:
        if device.FriendlyName == device_name:
            return device.id
    output_devices = get_list_of_active_coreaudio_devices("output")
    for device in output_devices:
        if device.FriendlyName == device_name:
            return device.id
    raise ValueError("Device not found!")

#Helper method to get all (active) devices
def get_list_of_active_coreaudio_devices(device_type:str) -> list:
    import comtypes
    from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IMMDeviceEnumerator, EDataFlow, DEVICE_STATE
    from pycaw.constants import CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator

    if device_type != "output" and device_type != "input":
        raise ValueError("Invalid audio device type.")

    if device_type == "output":
        EDataFlowValue = EDataFlow.eRender.value
    else:
        EDataFlowValue = EDataFlow.eCapture.value
    # Code to enumerate devices adapted from https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/issues/50#issuecomment-981069603

    devices = list()
    device_enumerator = comtypes.CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,
        IMMDeviceEnumerator,
        comtypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)
    if device_enumerator is None:
        raise ValueError("Couldn't find any devices.")
    collection = device_enumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(EDataFlowValue, DEVICE_STATE.ACTIVE.value)
    if collection is None:
        raise ValueError("Couldn't find any devices.")

    count = collection.GetCount()
    for i in range(count):
        dev = collection.Item(i)
        if dev is not None:
            if not ": None" in str(AudioUtilities.CreateDevice(dev)):
                devices.append(AudioUtilities.CreateDevice(dev))

    return devices

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```