# How to set "Listen to this device" with C# on windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows, audio, settings

Is there any way to toggle the microphone setting "listen to this device" in C# program on a windows 10 computer? Maybe with some registry settings or something?

I'm using AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio to find my microphone

[image: system settings]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# enable audio setting "listen to this device" in system control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406397/c-sharp-enable-audio-setting-listen-to-this-device-in-system-control) and [Reverse engineer Listen to this device on Windows - Reverse Engineer Windows When There's No API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929296/reverse-engineer-listen-to-this-device-on-windows-reverse-engineer-windows-whe)